# C program to enter basic salary and calculate gross salary of an employee using IF_ELSE statements

Tags: c, if-statement

Hello again I'm stuck with this program I think I have a logical problem , it's returning the same input I gave , without calculating the gross salary or DA or anything

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()

{
    float da, hra, salary;

    puts("simple program to calculate gross salary");
    printf("enter your salary : ");
    scanf("%f", &salary);

    if(salary<=10000)
    {
        hra = salary * (20/100);
        da = salary * (80/100);
        salary += hra + da;
    }
    else if(salary<=20000)
    {
        hra = salary * (25/100);
        da = salary * (90/100);
        salary += hra + da;
    }
    else if(salary>20000)
    {
        hra = salary * (30/100);
        da = salary * (95/100);
        salary += hra + da;
    }

    printf("\nyour gross salary is %.2f\n\n", salary);

}
```

Comment: `20/100` is integer division so the result will be an integer, or always 0. Try `20.0f/100.0f`

Comment: Or remove the parentheses, so the multiplication is done in floating point, before the division.

Comment: Aside: `if(salary>20000)` is unnecessary.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thakn you very much now I understand can you write it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: @WeatherVane I need just else .  thank you